# how to display array in array angular 4

Tags: angular

I want to display this list, but I could not access town attribute.

How could I fix my pb?

```
{ "id":"1",
      "name":"Hotel Ritz",
      "address":[
        {
         "country":"France",
         "town":"Paris",
        }
      ],
      "visited":true
    }
    { 
      "id":"2",
      "name":"The Plaza",
      "address":[
        {
         "country":"USA",
         "town":"New York"
        }
      ],
      "visited":false
    }
```

And what's the best method to display a checkbox to change the value of attribute visited?
I tried this code but it does not work:

```
 <ul class="hotel-list">  
      <li ng-repeat="hotel in hotels">
        <span>{{hotel.name}}<span>
      </li> 
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let towm of hotel.address">{{address.town}}</li>
     </ul>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `ng-repeat` is `angularjs` syntax. `*ngFor` is `angular` syntax. You can't mix/match these, pick the correct syntax for the framework you are using.
- In the HTML you reference `towm` which should be `town`
- If you use `let addressPart` in your `ngFor` then you can reference that directly inside the scope of that element.
- Your HTML syntax is not correct. `ul` contains `li` and not another `ul` element directly in it. You also have elements that don not have a matching closing tag.

---

```
<ul class="hotel-list">  
    <li *ngFor="let hotel of hotels">
        <span>{{hotel.name}}<span>
        <br/>
        Visited: <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="hotel.visited" />
    </li> 
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let addressPart of hotel.address">{{addressPart.town}}</li>
        </ul>
    </li> 
</ul>
```

Binding a value, like the `visited` property to a `checkbox`, is core concept of `angular`. In the above example I added 2 way binding. You can see more in the [Template Syntax](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#binding-syntax-an-overview) documentation.

Overall the angular documentation is very well written and has everything from [tutorials](https://angular.io/tutorial) to [fundamental concepts](https://angular.io/guide/architecture) to in depth [API documentation](https://angular.io/api). I recommend you check it out.